# Questions on piso shift register and simulating in LTspice

Tags: ltspice, shift-register

After my [previous](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/480612/help-with-understanding-the-mechanism-of-this-parallel-to-serial-shift-register) question, I attempted to simulate an 8-bit "parallel in serial out" shift register in LTspice as follows:

[image]

The above schematic is not very readable due to its size so below is the left half to see better:

[image]
*(left click to enlarge)*

And here below is the right half:

[image]
*(left click to enlarge)*

The B0, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7 are the bits of a parallel 8-bit data waiting to be sent as serial. So in the above example you can see the data is set to: 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1. Below red plot shows this as serial output along with the clock and the shift/load' control:

[image]

The reason I wanted to simulate this was to understand how UART works in principle.

My questions are:

1. Since it takes two clocks to output a bit according to the above
   simulation, can we say that the clock is always twice the baud-rate
   of the serial communication?
2. In the simulation above, right after the eight bit data is
   output/sent, the rest of the bits will be zero(red plot). The data bits are
   always the same B0 upto B7. How can we send this data continuously
   like 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 and then again 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 periodically?
   How does it happen in real? Do we need to reset the D flip flops?
   after each byte?

Here is the asc file:

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 6208 780
WIRE 5408 -336 5408 -544
WIRE 5536 -336 5408 -336
WIRE 5920 -336 5872 -336
WIRE 5328 -320 5296 -320
WIRE 5536 -320 5392 -320
WIRE 5632 -320 5600 -320
WIRE 5536 -304 5520 -304
WIRE 5520 -288 5520 -304
WIRE 5536 -288 5520 -288
WIRE 4640 -272 4640 -544
WIRE 4768 -272 4640 -272
WIRE 5152 -272 5104 -272
WIRE 5520 -272 5520 -288
WIRE 5536 -272 5520 -272
WIRE 5632 -272 5632 -320
WIRE 5680 -272 5632 -272
WIRE 4560 -256 4528 -256
WIRE 4768 -256 4624 -256
WIRE 4864 -256 4832 -256
WIRE 5520 -256 5520 -272
WIRE 5552 -256 5552 -272
WIRE 5552 -256 5520 -256
WIRE 5680 -256 5632 -256
WIRE 5744 -256 5728 -256
WIRE 5824 -256 5744 -256
WIRE 5856 -256 5824 -256
WIRE 6064 -256 6016 -256
WIRE 4768 -240 4752 -240
WIRE 5680 -240 5664 -240
WIRE 4752 -224 4752 -240
WIRE 4768 -224 4752 -224
WIRE 5664 -224 5664 -240
WIRE 5680 -224 5664 -224
WIRE 5824 -224 5792 -224
WIRE 3920 -208 3920 -544
WIRE 4048 -208 3920 -208
WIRE 4400 -208 4384 -208
WIRE 4752 -208 4752 -224
WIRE 4768 -208 4752 -208
WIRE 4864 -208 4864 -256
WIRE 4912 -208 4864 -208
WIRE 5296 -208 5296 -320
WIRE 5536 -208 5296 -208
WIRE 5664 -208 5664 -224
WIRE 5680 -208 5664 -208
WIRE 3840 -192 3808 -192
WIRE 4048 -192 3904 -192
WIRE 4144 -192 4112 -192
WIRE 4752 -192 4752 -208
WIRE 4784 -192 4784 -208
WIRE 4784 -192 4752 -192
WIRE 4912 -192 4864 -192
WIRE 4976 -192 4960 -192
WIRE 5056 -192 4976 -192
WIRE 5088 -192 5056 -192
WIRE 5536 -192 5248 -192
WIRE 5632 -192 5632 -256
WIRE 5632 -192 5600 -192
WIRE 5664 -192 5664 -208
WIRE 5696 -192 5696 -208
WIRE 5696 -192 5664 -192
WIRE 4048 -176 4032 -176
WIRE 4912 -176 4896 -176
WIRE 5536 -176 5520 -176
WIRE 4032 -160 4032 -176
WIRE 4048 -160 4032 -160
WIRE 4896 -160 4896 -176
WIRE 4912 -160 4896 -160
WIRE 5056 -160 5024 -160
WIRE 5520 -160 5520 -176
WIRE 5536 -160 5520 -160
WIRE 3104 -144 3104 -544
WIRE 3232 -144 3104 -144
WIRE 3664 -144 3616 -144
WIRE 4032 -144 4032 -160
WIRE 4048 -144 4032 -144
WIRE 4144 -144 4144 -192
WIRE 4192 -144 4144 -144
WIRE 4528 -144 4528 -256
WIRE 4768 -144 4528 -144
WIRE 4896 -144 4896 -160
WIRE 4912 -144 4896 -144
WIRE 5520 -144 5520 -160
WIRE 5536 -144 5520 -144
WIRE 3024 -128 2992 -128
WIRE 3232 -128 3088 -128
WIRE 3328 -128 3296 -128
WIRE 4032 -128 4032 -144
WIRE 4064 -128 4064 -144
WIRE 4064 -128 4032 -128
WIRE 4192 -128 4144 -128
WIRE 4256 -128 4240 -128
WIRE 4304 -128 4256 -128
WIRE 4768 -128 4496 -128
WIRE 4864 -128 4864 -192
WIRE 4864 -128 4832 -128
WIRE 4896 -128 4896 -144
WIRE 4928 -128 4928 -144
WIRE 4928 -128 4896 -128
WIRE 5520 -128 5520 -144
WIRE 5552 -128 5552 -144
WIRE 5552 -128 5520 -128
WIRE 3232 -112 3216 -112
WIRE 4192 -112 4176 -112
WIRE 4768 -112 4752 -112
WIRE 5920 -112 5888 -112
WIRE 3216 -96 3216 -112
WIRE 3232 -96 3216 -96
WIRE 4176 -96 4176 -112
WIRE 4192 -96 4176 -96
WIRE 4304 -96 4288 -96
WIRE 4752 -96 4752 -112
WIRE 4768 -96 4752 -96
WIRE 2336 -80 2336 -544
WIRE 2464 -80 2336 -80
WIRE 2848 -80 2800 -80
WIRE 3216 -80 3216 -96
WIRE 3232 -80 3216 -80
WIRE 3328 -80 3328 -128
WIRE 3376 -80 3328 -80
WIRE 3808 -80 3808 -192
WIRE 4048 -80 3808 -80
WIRE 4176 -80 4176 -96
WIRE 4192 -80 4176 -80
WIRE 4752 -80 4752 -96
WIRE 4768 -80 4752 -80
WIRE -1152 -64 -1152 -80
WIRE -1040 -64 -1040 -80
WIRE -928 -64 -928 -80
WIRE -816 -64 -816 -80
WIRE -704 -64 -704 -80
WIRE -592 -64 -592 -80
WIRE -480 -64 -480 -80
WIRE -368 -64 -368 -80
WIRE 2256 -64 2224 -64
WIRE 2464 -64 2320 -64
WIRE 2560 -64 2528 -64
WIRE 3216 -64 3216 -80
WIRE 3248 -64 3248 -80
WIRE 3248 -64 3216 -64
WIRE 3376 -64 3328 -64
WIRE 3568 -64 3440 -64
WIRE 3584 -64 3568 -64
WIRE 4048 -64 3760 -64
WIRE 4144 -64 4144 -128
WIRE 4144 -64 4112 -64
WIRE 4176 -64 4176 -80
WIRE 4208 -64 4208 -80
WIRE 4208 -64 4176 -64
WIRE 4752 -64 4752 -80
WIRE 4784 -64 4784 -80
WIRE 4784 -64 4752 -64
WIRE 2464 -48 2448 -48
WIRE 3376 -48 3360 -48
WIRE 4048 -48 4032 -48
WIRE 5152 -48 5120 -48
WIRE 2448 -32 2448 -48
WIRE 2464 -32 2448 -32
WIRE 3360 -32 3360 -48
WIRE 3376 -32 3360 -32
WIRE 3568 -32 3488 -32
WIRE 4032 -32 4032 -48
WIRE 4048 -32 4032 -32
WIRE 1568 -16 1568 -544
WIRE 1696 -16 1568 -16
WIRE 2080 -16 2032 -16
WIRE 2448 -16 2448 -32
WIRE 2464 -16 2448 -16
WIRE 2560 -16 2560 -64
WIRE 2608 -16 2560 -16
WIRE 2992 -16 2992 -128
WIRE 3232 -16 2992 -16
WIRE 3360 -16 3360 -32
WIRE 3376 -16 3360 -16
WIRE 4032 -16 4032 -32
WIRE 4048 -16 4032 -16
WIRE 1488 0 1456 0
WIRE 1696 0 1552 0
WIRE 1792 0 1760 0
WIRE 2448 0 2448 -16
WIRE 2480 0 2480 -16
WIRE 2480 0 2448 0
WIRE 2608 0 2560 0
WIRE 2672 0 2656 0
WIRE 2752 0 2672 0
WIRE 2784 0 2752 0
WIRE 2944 0 2928 0
WIRE 3232 0 2944 0
WIRE 3328 0 3328 -64
WIRE 3328 0 3296 0
WIRE 3360 0 3360 -16
WIRE 3392 0 3392 -16
WIRE 3392 0 3360 0
WIRE 4032 0 4032 -16
WIRE 4064 0 4064 -16
WIRE 4064 0 4032 0
WIRE 1696 16 1680 16
WIRE 2608 16 2592 16
WIRE 3232 16 3216 16
WIRE 4400 16 4384 16
WIRE 1680 32 1680 16
WIRE 1696 32 1680 32
WIRE 2592 32 2592 16
WIRE 2608 32 2592 32
WIRE 2752 32 2720 32
WIRE 3216 32 3216 16
WIRE 3232 32 3216 32
WIRE -1152 48 -1152 16
WIRE -1040 48 -1040 16
WIRE -928 48 -928 16
WIRE -816 48 -816 16
WIRE -704 48 -704 16
WIRE -592 48 -592 16
WIRE -480 48 -480 16
WIRE -368 48 -368 16
WIRE 848 48 848 -544
WIRE 976 48 848 48
WIRE 1328 48 1312 48
WIRE 1680 48 1680 32
WIRE 1696 48 1680 48
WIRE 1792 48 1792 0
WIRE 1840 48 1792 48
WIRE 2224 48 2224 -64
WIRE 2464 48 2224 48
WIRE 2592 48 2592 32
WIRE 2608 48 2592 48
WIRE 3216 48 3216 32
WIRE 3232 48 3216 48
WIRE 768 64 736 64
WIRE 976 64 832 64
WIRE 1072 64 1040 64
WIRE 1680 64 1680 48
WIRE 1712 64 1712 48
WIRE 1712 64 1680 64
WIRE 1840 64 1792 64
WIRE 1904 64 1888 64
WIRE 1984 64 1904 64
WIRE 2016 64 1984 64
WIRE 2464 64 2176 64
WIRE 2560 64 2560 0
WIRE 2560 64 2528 64
WIRE 2592 64 2592 48
WIRE 2624 64 2624 48
WIRE 2624 64 2592 64
WIRE 3216 64 3216 48
WIRE 3248 64 3248 48
WIRE 3248 64 3216 64
WIRE 976 80 960 80
WIRE 1840 80 1824 80
WIRE 2464 80 2448 80
WIRE 3664 80 3632 80
WIRE 960 96 960 80
WIRE 976 96 960 96
WIRE 1824 96 1824 80
WIRE 1840 96 1824 96
WIRE 1984 96 1952 96
WIRE 2448 96 2448 80
WIRE 2464 96 2448 96
WIRE 32 112 32 -544
WIRE 160 112 32 112
WIRE 592 112 544 112
WIRE 960 112 960 96
WIRE 976 112 960 112
WIRE 1072 112 1072 64
WIRE 1120 112 1072 112
WIRE 1456 112 1456 0
WIRE 1696 112 1456 112
WIRE 1824 112 1824 96
WIRE 1840 112 1824 112
WIRE 2448 112 2448 96
WIRE 2464 112 2448 112
WIRE -48 128 -80 128
WIRE 160 128 16 128
WIRE 256 128 224 128
WIRE 960 128 960 112
WIRE 992 128 992 112
WIRE 992 128 960 128
WIRE 1120 128 1072 128
WIRE 1184 128 1168 128
WIRE 1232 128 1184 128
WIRE 1696 128 1424 128
WIRE 1792 128 1792 64
WIRE 1792 128 1760 128
WIRE 1824 128 1824 112
WIRE 1856 128 1856 112
WIRE 1856 128 1824 128
WIRE 2448 128 2448 112
WIRE 2480 128 2480 112
WIRE 2480 128 2448 128
WIRE 160 144 144 144
WIRE 1120 144 1104 144
WIRE 1696 144 1680 144
WIRE 2848 144 2816 144
WIRE 144 160 144 144
WIRE 160 160 144 160
WIRE 1104 160 1104 144
WIRE 1120 160 1104 160
WIRE 1232 160 1216 160
WIRE 1680 160 1680 144
WIRE 1696 160 1680 160
WIRE 144 176 144 160
WIRE 160 176 144 176
WIRE 256 176 256 128
WIRE 304 176 256 176
WIRE 736 176 736 64
WIRE 976 176 736 176
WIRE 1104 176 1104 160
WIRE 1120 176 1104 176
WIRE 1680 176 1680 160
WIRE 1696 176 1680 176
WIRE 144 192 144 176
WIRE 176 192 176 176
WIRE 176 192 144 192
WIRE 304 192 256 192
WIRE 496 192 368 192
WIRE 512 192 496 192
WIRE 976 192 688 192
WIRE 1072 192 1072 128
WIRE 1072 192 1040 192
WIRE 1104 192 1104 176
WIRE 1136 192 1136 176
WIRE 1136 192 1104 192
WIRE 1680 192 1680 176
WIRE 1712 192 1712 176
WIRE 1712 192 1680 192
WIRE 3488 192 3488 -32
WIRE 4288 192 4288 -96
WIRE 4288 192 3488 192
WIRE 5024 192 5024 -160
WIRE 5024 192 4288 192
WIRE 5792 192 5792 -224
WIRE 5792 192 5024 192
WIRE 304 208 288 208
WIRE 976 208 960 208
WIRE 2080 208 2048 208
WIRE 288 224 288 208
WIRE 304 224 288 224
WIRE 496 224 416 224
WIRE 960 224 960 208
WIRE 976 224 960 224
WIRE -80 240 -80 128
WIRE 160 240 -80 240
WIRE 288 240 288 224
WIRE 304 240 288 240
WIRE 960 240 960 224
WIRE 976 240 960 240
WIRE 160 256 -32 256
WIRE 256 256 256 192
WIRE 256 256 224 256
WIRE 288 256 288 240
WIRE 320 256 320 240
WIRE 320 256 288 256
WIRE 960 256 960 240
WIRE 992 256 992 240
WIRE 992 256 960 256
WIRE 160 272 144 272
WIRE 1328 272 1312 272
WIRE 144 288 144 272
WIRE 160 288 144 288
WIRE 144 304 144 288
WIRE 160 304 144 304
WIRE 144 320 144 304
WIRE 176 320 176 304
WIRE 176 320 144 320
WIRE 2992 320 2992 -16
WIRE 3808 320 3808 -80
WIRE 3808 320 2992 320
WIRE 4528 320 4528 -144
WIRE 4528 320 3808 320
WIRE 5296 320 5296 -208
WIRE 5296 320 4528 320
WIRE 592 336 560 336
WIRE 416 448 416 224
WIRE 1216 448 1216 160
WIRE 1216 448 416 448
WIRE 1952 448 1952 96
WIRE 1952 448 1216 448
WIRE 2720 448 2720 32
WIRE 2720 448 1952 448
WIRE 3488 448 3488 192
WIRE 3488 448 2720 448
WIRE -704 464 -704 448
WIRE -608 464 -608 448
WIRE -496 464 -496 448
WIRE -704 576 -704 544
WIRE -608 576 -608 544
WIRE -496 576 -496 544
WIRE -80 576 -80 240
WIRE 736 576 736 176
WIRE 736 576 -80 576
WIRE 1456 576 1456 112
WIRE 1456 576 736 576
WIRE 2224 576 2224 48
WIRE 2224 576 1456 576
WIRE 2992 576 2992 320
WIRE 2992 576 2224 576
WIRE -80 704 -80 576
WIRE -80 704 -96 704
WIRE 416 704 416 448
WIRE 416 704 336 704
FLAG 176 192 0
FLAG 176 320 0
FLAG 320 256 0
FLAG -48 144 0
FLAG -96 704 SHIFT\LD
FLAG 32 -544 B7
FLAG -1152 48 0
FLAG -704 576 0
FLAG -1152 -80 B7
FLAG -704 448 SHIFT\LD
FLAG 336 704 CLK
FLAG -496 576 0
FLAG -496 448 CLK
FLAG -608 576 0
FLAG -608 448 Vcc
FLAG 544 112 Vcc
FLAG 560 336 Vcc
FLAG 992 128 0
FLAG 992 256 0
FLAG 1136 192 0
FLAG 768 80 0
FLAG 848 -544 B6
FLAG 1312 48 Vcc
FLAG 1312 272 Vcc
FLAG 1712 64 0
FLAG 1712 192 0
FLAG 1856 128 0
FLAG 1488 16 0
FLAG 1568 -544 B5
FLAG 2032 -16 Vcc
FLAG 2048 208 Vcc
FLAG -1040 48 0
FLAG -1040 -80 B6
FLAG -928 48 0
FLAG -928 -80 B5
FLAG 2480 0 0
FLAG 2480 128 0
FLAG 2624 64 0
FLAG 2256 -48 0
FLAG 2336 -544 B4
FLAG 2800 -80 Vcc
FLAG 2816 144 Vcc
FLAG -816 48 0
FLAG -816 -80 B4
FLAG 3248 -64 0
FLAG 3248 64 0
FLAG 3392 0 0
FLAG 3024 -112 0
FLAG 3104 -544 B3
FLAG -704 48 0
FLAG -704 -80 B3
FLAG 3616 -144 Vcc
FLAG 3632 80 Vcc
FLAG 4064 -128 0
FLAG 4064 0 0
FLAG 4208 -64 0
FLAG 3840 -176 0
FLAG 3920 -544 B2
FLAG 4384 -208 Vcc
FLAG 4384 16 Vcc
FLAG 4784 -192 0
FLAG 4784 -64 0
FLAG 4928 -128 0
FLAG 4560 -240 0
FLAG 4640 -544 B1
FLAG 5104 -272 Vcc
FLAG 5120 -48 Vcc
FLAG -592 48 0
FLAG -592 -80 B2
FLAG -480 48 0
FLAG -480 -80 B1
FLAG 5552 -256 0
FLAG 5552 -128 0
FLAG 5696 -192 0
FLAG 5328 -304 0
FLAG 5408 -544 B0
FLAG 5872 -336 Vcc
FLAG 5888 -112 Vcc
FLAG 6064 -256 out
IOPIN 6064 -256 Out
FLAG -368 48 0
FLAG -368 -80 B0
SYMBOL Digital\\and 192 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL Digital\\and 192 208 R0
SYMATTR InstName A2
SYMBOL Digital\\or 336 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName A3
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv -48 64 R0
SYMATTR InstName A4
SYMBOL voltage -1152 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage -704 448 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 3 -322 173 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 0.1 1n 1n 0.05 0.1)
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL voltage -496 448 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 3 -285 203 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 5 0.03 1n 1n 0.05 0.1)
SYMATTR InstName V4
SYMBOL voltage -608 448 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V5
SYMATTR Value 5
SYMBOL 74hct74 592 112 R0
SYMATTR InstName U2
SYMBOL Digital\\and 1008 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName A5
SYMBOL Digital\\and 1008 144 R0
SYMATTR InstName A6
SYMBOL Digital\\or 1152 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName A7
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 768 0 R0
SYMATTR InstName A8
SYMBOL 74hct74 1328 48 R0
SYMATTR InstName U1
SYMBOL Digital\\and 1728 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName A9
SYMBOL Digital\\and 1728 80 R0
SYMATTR InstName A10
SYMBOL Digital\\or 1872 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName A11
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 1488 -64 R0
SYMATTR InstName A12
SYMBOL 74hct74 2080 -16 R0
SYMATTR InstName U3
SYMBOL voltage -1040 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V6
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL voltage -928 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V7
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL Digital\\and 2496 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName A13
SYMBOL Digital\\and 2496 16 R0
SYMATTR InstName A14
SYMBOL Digital\\or 2640 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName A15
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 2256 -128 R0
SYMATTR InstName A16
SYMBOL 74hct74 2848 -80 R0
SYMATTR InstName U4
SYMBOL voltage -816 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL Digital\\and 3264 -176 R0
SYMATTR InstName A17
SYMBOL Digital\\and 3264 -48 R0
SYMATTR InstName A18
SYMBOL Digital\\or 3408 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName A19
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 3024 -192 R0
SYMATTR InstName A20
SYMBOL voltage -704 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V8
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL 74hct74 3664 -144 R0
SYMATTR InstName U5
SYMBOL Digital\\and 4080 -240 R0
SYMATTR InstName A21
SYMBOL Digital\\and 4080 -112 R0
SYMATTR InstName A22
SYMBOL Digital\\or 4224 -176 R0
SYMATTR InstName A23
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 3840 -256 R0
SYMATTR InstName A24
SYMBOL 74hct74 4400 -208 R0
SYMATTR InstName U6
SYMBOL Digital\\and 4800 -304 R0
SYMATTR InstName A25
SYMBOL Digital\\and 4800 -176 R0
SYMATTR InstName A26
SYMBOL Digital\\or 4944 -240 R0
SYMATTR InstName A27
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 4560 -320 R0
SYMATTR InstName A28
SYMBOL 74hct74 5152 -272 R0
SYMATTR InstName U7
SYMBOL voltage -592 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V12
SYMATTR Value 0
SYMBOL voltage -480 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V13
SYMATTR Value 1
SYMBOL Digital\\and 5568 -368 R0
SYMATTR InstName A29
SYMBOL Digital\\and 5568 -240 R0
SYMATTR InstName A30
SYMBOL Digital\\or 5712 -304 R0
SYMATTR InstName A31
SYMATTR SpiceLine Vhigh=5 Vlow=0 Ref=0.5
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 5328 -384 R0
SYMATTR InstName A32
SYMBOL 74hct74 5920 -336 R0
SYMATTR InstName U8
SYMBOL voltage -368 -80 M0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 0
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 0
SYMATTR InstName V14
SYMATTR Value 1
TEXT -776 680 Left 2 !.tran 1.6
TEXT 560 400 Left 2 !.lib 74HCT.lib
RECTANGLE Normal -304 704 -816 304 2
RECTANGLE Normal -320 112 -1232 -144 2
```

Comment: A bit unrelated to your question, the schematic you posted is useless for anyone that doesn't have the custom library (`74HCT.lib`) and symbol(s). It looks like you made use of LTspice's sym & lib custom paths, which is convenient only for that user in particular. If you'd want to send this schematic to someone and expect that someone to be able to use it, you'd have to pack the schematic, symbol(s), and library/ies (usually an archive, for compactness). Now it may not be needed since it looks like you have an answer (which you should mark as accepted, if true, for future searches).

Comment: You say you want to simulate how a UART really works BUT are trying to do things which most UARTS do not do. | A UART will usually accept parallel data with a load signal, output that data in bit serial, usually with an added start bit and 1, 1.5 or 2 stop bits, then stop sending until another load occurs. Usually the UART is "buffered" with a short FIFO (usually one register two data words long including currently sending data) to ensure that data is always available under continuous use. There is no "magic". All the decisions about load, add start bits, shift, add stop bits, stop sending .

Comment: ... are logically implemented functions using whatever method of gates etc that suit the designer. There is no one guaranteed method or circuit and you are free to implement you own. State machine, ... . || Load signal: Load daata to buffer. | If not sending: transfer buffer to active register. Set Dout low, send start bit, send 8 data bits. Set Dout high. Send stop bit (or two or ...). | If buffer has data load data and repeat. Otherwise stop.

Answer (score 0):

1) It does not take two clocks per bit, the waveform clearly shows output bit is updated once per clock cycle, on the rising edge, so bit rate is exactly same as clock rate.

2) You need to keep count of clock cycles and periodically reload the shift registers at a rate you want to transmit the byte again.

Comment: Reagrding "periodically reload the shift registers". What is missing in my case? Should  I reset the D flip flops after each 8 clocks?

Comment: Alternatively, simply feed the serial output of the shift register back to the serial input (that dangling input on the leftmost mux in your diagram). Then you only need to do a parallel load when you want to change the pattern being sent.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks. As you suggested, I fed the serial output of the shift register back to the floating input of the leftmost MUX. Now it sends continuous/periodic 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 bit pattern. Seems like LTspice is not the best program to learn digital electronics(especially in my case UART communication).